# how to use framework using Cmake?

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

For Macos, I'd like to link to some framework. In windows, I would like to link to some library.

For example, OpenGL Framework, how to express this requirement using cmake?

Answer (score 12):

You could try the following code:

```
target_link_libraries(<target name>
    "-framework AVFoundation"
    "-framework CoreGraphics"
    "-framework CoreMotion"
    "-framework Foundation"
    "-framework MediaPlayer"
    "-framework OpenGLES"
    "-framework QuartzCore"
    "-framework UIKit"
    )
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks! However, I'm getting parse error in the generated CMakeCache.txt afterward.

Comment: This doesn't address the windows part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

To tell CMake that you want to link to OpenGL, add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(<your program name> ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

`find_package` will look for OpenGL and tell the rest of the script where OpenGL is by setting some OPENGL* variables. `include_directories` tells your compiler where to find OpenGL headers. `target_link_libraries` instructs CMake to link in OpenGL.

The following code will do different actions based on the operating system:

```
if(WIN32)
    #Windows specific code
elseif(APPLE)
    #OSX specific code
endif()
```

Comment: I am wondering if this works for Win32? I think it works for OSX

Comment: Where does it get variables OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR and OPENGL_LIBRARIES? Is it some sort of all preloaded variables? For opengl, for curl, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following macro code:

```
macro(ADD_OSX_FRAMEWORK fwname target)
    find_library(FRAMEWORK_${fwname}
    NAMES ${fwname}
    PATHS ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library
    PATH_SUFFIXES Frameworks
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    if( ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}} STREQUAL FRAMEWORK_${fwname}-NOTFOUND)
        MESSAGE(ERROR ": Framework ${fwname} not found")
    else()
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${target} PUBLIC "${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}/${fwname}")
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Framework ${fwname} found at ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}")
    endif()
endmacro(ADD_OSX_FRAMEWORK)
```

**Example**

```
ADD_OSX_FRAMEWORK(Foundation ${YOUR_TARGET}) # Add the foundation OSX Framework
```

You can find this example code [here](https://www.biicode.com/biicode/cmake)

Comment: Typically the target is the first argument of commands like this, no?

Answer (score 1):

For custom framework

`cmake version 3.20.1`

https://github.com/Sunbreak/cli-breakpad.trial/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L10-L12

```sh
if(APPLE)
    find_library(BREAKPAD_CLIENT Breakpad "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/breakpad/mac/")
    target_link_libraries(cli-breakpad PRIVATE ${BREAKPAD_CLIENT})
```