# How to use Cmake ExternalProject_Add to add a library from github

Tags: c++, git, opengl, cmake, compilation

I am trying to clone and build 3rd party libraries from git using Cmake's `ExternalProject_Add`.

Could someone please explain to me how to use `ExternalProject_Add` correctly?

Currently I have this in my CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(openGLtest)

include(ExternalProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(OUTPUT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreVideo")

ExternalProject_Add(glfw
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
        CMAKE_ARGS  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${OUTPUT_DIR})

include_directories(glad/include)
include_directories(${OUTPUT_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${OUTPUT_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(openGLtest glad/src/glad.c main.cpp)
add_dependencies(openGLtest glfw)
target_link_libraries(openGLtest glfw3.a)
```

I'm using `GLFW`, and `GLAD`. The issue is that `GLFW`'s dependencies are not being linked when it get's compiled, that's why I added the set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` line. Everything compiles now, but I am pretty sure that shoehorning in system specific compiler flags is not the right solution.

-EDIT-

My problem is not with this library specifically, it's about the finding the correct way of setting up my Cmake to get the libraries that my project needs from the internet when I build the project. I'm sure Cmake is capable of pulling, or downloading the necessary libraries when it builds my project. It also seems to me that using `ExternalProject_Add` is the right way to do that. I just don't know how to use `ExternalProject_Add` to get the libraries, without there being weird compile errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck with this problem for almost a week at this point.

Comment: "I am pretty sure that shoehorning in system specific compiler flags is not the right solution." - If you mean, that setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` isn't a true way, then you are right: In CMake, `-framework` option is passed via `target_link_libraries` call (see e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585896/how-to-use-framework-using-cmake)).

Comment: You’re right, that would make things better, but it still won’t completely solve the problem. By that I mean my inclusion of the GLFW library would still not be correct, because I’m still manually linking the library’s dependencies. From what I understand it is possible to build GLFW from source, so that it automatically detects which system it’s being built on, and the automatically links the correct dependencies. That is what I’m trying to achieve with ExternalProject_Add, but I don’t know why it’s not working.

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add` operates at build-time. If you want to make sure downloading happens at configure-time, consider using [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html), which wraps the parts of `ExternalProject_Add` that do the download, update, and patch steps, and then does the rest with `add_subdirectory` instead of requiring installing the external project and then adding it with `find_package`.

Comment: When you use `ExternalProject`, you need to set up a lot of boilerplate to make the external project use the same settings as the "parent" project, such as the toolchain file, c++ compiler, c++ standard, configuration types / build type, etc. There are pros and cons to choosing `ExternalProject` vs `FetchContent` that mostly revolve around how much control you want/need when it comes to isolating the configs of the top-level and external projects from each other.